# Custom category attribute is not being saved - issue

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, category-attribute

I managed to create my custom attribute:

```
    $installer = $setup;
    $installer->startSetup();
    $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $categorySetup->addAttribute(
        Category::ENTITY,
        'content_category_page',
        [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Content Page',
            'input' => 'select',
            'sort_order' => 100,
            'source' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Page',
            'global' => 2,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => null,
            'group' => 'General Information',
            'backend' => ''
        ]
    );
    $installer->endSetup();
```

I made the file `view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="content_category_page">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\Config\ContentPages</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Content Page</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">content_category_page</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The new attribute appeared in the right place, but when i choose an option and press the save button, the value is not being saved . Would you please advice, why my custom category attribute is not created ? :)  Thnx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use the the `UpgradeData`: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-how-to-create-sql-setup-script.html#upgrade-data

My module already had a version so I needed to increase that as well.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can create Custom Attribute, place this code with your changes under Setup/installData.php

```
namespace AWstreams\Sonic\Setup;
    use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
        {
        /**
         * @var CustomerSetupFactory
         */
        protected $customerSetupFactory;
        /**
         * @var AttributeSetFactory
         */
        private $attributeSetFactory;
        /**
         * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
         * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
            AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
        ) {
            $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
            $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        }
        public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
            {
            /*customersetupfactory instead of eavsetupfactory */
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
                $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
            /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
                    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
                    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
                        /* create customer merchant attribute */
                        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY,'customer_code',  [
                        'type'         => 'varchar',
                        'label'        => 'Sonic Customer Code',
                        'input'        => 'text',
                        'source' => '',
                        'required'     => false,
                        'visible'      => false,
                        'default' => '0',
                        'user_defined' => true,
                        'position'     => 332,
                        'sort_order'  => 332,
                        'system'       => 0,
                        'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                        'backend' => '',
                        ]
                        );
                    $sampleAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_code')
                    ->addData(
                    [
                                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit','customer_account_create'],
                            ]
                    );
                    $sampleAttribute->save();
                    }
            }
```

after that, run

> setup:upgrade command

Comment: hmm this looks like to be a customer attribute not a category attribute.  I need to use the UpgradeData since i already have a version.